# Meaning of $\frac{P(X\cap Y)}{P(X)P(Y)}$

Tags: probability, statistics

Imagine that we have a set $\Omega$ and $X$ and $Y$ are events that can happen, I mean, $P(X),P(Y)>0$. Then, what does it mean the ratio $\frac{P(X\cap Y)}{P(X)P(Y)}$?

I know that $\frac{P(X\cap Y)}{P(X)P(Y)}=\frac{P(X|Y)}{P(X)}=\frac{P(Y|X)}{P(Y)}$ and if that ratio is equal to 1 then $X,Y$ are independent events, but I can't figure out what exactly it means... please give simple examples.

I found this when reading about lift-data mining.

Comment: Your equations are off.  it should have been $\dfrac{\Pr(X\mid Y)}{\Pr(\color{red}{X})}$.  Recall, $\Pr(X\cap Y)=\Pr(X\mid Y)\Pr(Y)$, the $\Pr(Y)$'s then cancel from numerator and denominator.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you, already fixed it

Comment: Now... as for what these results might intuitively signify... if $\frac{\Pr(X\mid Y)}{\Pr(X)}>1$ then that would tell you that $Y$ happening increases $X$'s chance of happening, i.e. that they are [correlated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation).  If the ratio is equal to $1$ then we know they are independent.  If the ratio is less than $1$ then we know they are inversely-correlated.  Note that the measure of how correlated two random variables are is often defined a different way, but this is another option which gives similar information.

Comment: @JMoravitz I agree, but perhaps *associated* is a better term than *correlated*, since we are not dealing with quantitative observations.

Comment: @HansEngler Can you explain that comment to me? I am not sure I understand the distinction you are making here. Is the correlation between events not usually defined through the indicator functions in your experience? i.e., Cov$(1_A,1_B) =  P(A,B) - P(A)P(B)$ and Corr$(1_A,1_B) = \frac{P(A,B)-P(A)P(B)}{\sqrt{P(A)(1-P(A)) P(B)(1-P(B))}}$, using the usual definitions.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian You are right in that a correlation coefficient can be defined for any two r.v. if their joint distribution is known, including indicator functions. In my comment, I am referring to the use of the terms "correlation" and "association" in statistics, not to their use in probability theory, which is slightly different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ratio $\frac{P(X\cap Y)}{P(X)P(Y)}=\frac{P(X|Y)}{P(X)}$ is called lift, and it is a measure of how good the occurrence of event $Y$ is at predicting the occurrence of event $X$. We interpret the lift as the ratio in which the probability of $X$ increases after the occurrence of $Y$. Notice that $\frac{P(X^c|Y)}{P(X^c)} = \frac{1 - P(X|Y)}{1 - P(X)} = \frac{1/P(X) - \text{lift}}{1/P(X) - 1}$, which is 1 precisely when lift $= 1$, and increases as lift increases. This is consistent with predicting the non occurrence of $X$ after $Y$ when lift $< 1$.

**Example:** $X$ is the event that this answer receives an up-vote. $Y$ is the event that I provide an example. In this case we expect lift $> 1$, as $Y$ is presumably associated with an increased probability of $X$.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_(data_mining))

Comment: good example, good answer

Answer (score 1):

As @JMoravitz noted, it's $\frac{P(X|Y)}{P(X)} = \frac{P(Y|X)}{P(Y)}$.

Let's call this ratio $r$. So if  $r>1$, then $P(X|Y) = r P(X) > P(X)$ and $P(Y|X) = r P(Y) > P(Y)$, and reverse inequalities hold if $r < 1$. Intuitively, if $r > 1$ and $Y$ has been observed, the probability of $X$ increases by this factor.

**Example:** Let $X$ be the event that you get COVID while spending an hour on the exercise bicycle in the gym and let $Y$ be the event that a person with asymptomatic COVID uses the bicycle next to you during this hour. Then $r$ measures the increase in risk due to the exposure to somebody with COVID who exercises next to you, and presumably $r > 1$.

Answer (score -1):

As @Chrisjanjigian has noted
Cov(1,1)=(,)−()()

So when covariance is zero P(A,B)=P(A)P(B)

And correlation is cov(AB)/[stdev(A)*stdev(B)]

The long answer:
[image]

We have balls in 2 pools and the square outside the pools. 40 balls are not in the pools, 25 in pool A, 35 in pool B. A total of 85 unique balls.
Here is the calculation to see if the events are independent or not. This example uses no measurements simply probabilities of 1 and 0 for each ball to calculate the covariance. Cov(AB)=P(AB)-P(A)P(B) = E[(A-P(A)(B-P(B)] =
Average((A-P(A)(B-P(B)) where A and B are either 1 or 0 for each of the 85 balls in the average based on whether it is or isnt in A or B

[image]